# Keep leading 0 in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

In my database, I have a field containing the following data : 000010 (the type is integer)

In my twig tpl, I want to display it, then I do : {{ spending.documentName }}

But the browser displays "10". As if Twig was automaticcaly performing a trim on my data.
I tried {{ spending.documentName|raw }} but it doesn't work. I dont find anything on Google about how to keep leading 0 with Twig.

Does anyone know how to proceed ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think you must force the format (as your type is integer).

You can use the format filter :

```
{{ "%06d"|format(spending.documentName) }}
```

Or better create a twig extension (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html):

```
public function strpad($number, $pad_length, $pad_string) {
    return str_pad($number, $pad_length, $pad_string, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

It's clearer in your template :

```
{{ spending.documentName | strpad(6,'0') }}
```

Comment: this works, but it makes my zero-leading stockage totally useless, as I have to reformat it before display. If i decide to change the number of leading zero in my db, i'll have to edit my template too. Anyway, i'll stick to that, can't find a better solution right now. anyway, this twig auto trim is really strange.

Comment: Do you use on ORM (like Doctrine) ? if so, i think it's the ORM that do the trim, not twig

Comment: I use doctrine. in my database, the value is correctly saved with leading zero. U think doctrine performs a trim during hydration ?

Comment: Yes, probably ; so you can also call str_pad in the getDocumentName function of the doctrine entity, but i think it's not the best solution

Comment: Have you found a solution to this @VaN? Is it indeed Doctrine who trims the zeros - even when using column definitions like options={"unsigned":true}, columnDefinition="SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL"?

Comment: Yes, I changed my property type from integer to string : ) Probably not the best solution ever, but it works. And it's actually correct for this property to be a string, as it represents a document name. With s string type, doctrine does not trim leading 0 during db insertion nor hydration.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the [`format`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/format.html) filter.

Since placeholders follows the `sprintf()` notation, you should be able to convert `sprintf('%06d', $integer);` in PHP to `{{ '%06d'|format($integer) }}` in Twig.

Answer (score 8):

Kinda late here, but ran into the same.

With twig 3.x you can use:

```
{{your.number | format_number({min_integer_digit:'2'})}}
```

Comment: The argument (`'2'`) needn't be a string. i.e. `{{ num|format_number({min_integer_digit: 2}) }}` should be considered correct.